# while compiling my code this error pops up org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, php, android, json, xml

**This is my Json coding**

while compiling my code this error pops up org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of and my xml page is displaying empty

Json coding

`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.ram.northmadras.URLs.articleconURL;
import static com.example.ram.northmadras.URLs.articlecon_tag;

class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getArticlecon(int startIndex){
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", articlecon_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("index",""+startIndex));
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject jsonObject= jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(articleconURL, params);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.getInt("max"); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                String json = jsonObject.getString("" + (i));
                json = json.replace("[", "");
                json = json.replace("]", "");
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(json);
                hashMap.put("Title", jsonObject1.getString("Title"));
                hashMap.put("Description", jsonObject1.getString("Description"));
                hashMap.put("Image", jsonObject1.getString("Image"));
                hashMap.put("PostedTime", jsonObject1.getString("PostedTime"));
                hashMap.put("PostedByName", jsonObject1.getString("postedByName"));
                arrayList.add(hashMap);
            }
        }catch (Exception ignored){}
        return arrayList;
    }
`  }
```

**This is my Json string. 
this is an php file**

articlecon.php

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') 
{
 $tag = $_POST['tag'];
  require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
  $db = new DB_Functions();
  $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);
 if ($tag == 'getarticlecon') 
  {
    $users = $db->getarticlecon($_POST['index']);
    if ($users != false)
        {
      $c=1;
      while ($user=mysql_fetch_assoc($users)) {
        $response[][]=$user;
        $c++;
      }
      $response["success"]=1;
      $response["max"]=$c;
      $response["itemsCount"]=7;
      echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
      $response["error"] = 1;
      $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
      echo json_encode($response);
    }
  }
}
```

?>

---

### DB_Functions.php

```
public function getarticlecon($index)
    {
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT Title,Description,Image,PostedTime,PostedByName FROM articles LIMIT 10 OFFSET $index ") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
      $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
      if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            //$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $result;            
      } else {
            // user not found
        return false;
      }
    }
```

---

**I using two java classes ArticleContent and CustomArticle Adapter**
These are my java_classes

ArticleContent.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class ArticleContent extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageview;
    static CustomArticleAdapter adapter;
    static int startIndex;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.article_content);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById((R.id.img1));
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        new ArticleContent.json(startIndex).execute();
        startIndex += 10;
        int[] ids = {R.id.textview1, R.id.textview2, R.id.textview3, R.id.textview4, R.id.img1};
        String[] keys = {"Title", "Description", "PostedTime", "PostedByName", "Image"};
        //adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ArticleContent.this, arrayList, R.layout.article_content, keys, ids);
        adapter=new CustomArticleAdapter(this,arrayList);
     //   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class json extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {

        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        int startIndex;
        public json(int startIndex) {
            this.startIndex=startIndex;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ArticleContent.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            arrayList.addAll(userFunction.getArticlecon(startIndex));
            try
            {
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("aaa123456",arrayList.toString());
            }
            return arrayList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {
            try {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("aaa7890123456",arrayList.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is an custom adapter class**

CustomArticleAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Ram on 2/23/2018.
 */

public class CustomArticleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> article;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public CustomArticleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> article) {
        this.context = context;
        this.article = article;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return article.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textviewa, textviewb, textviewc, textviewd;
        ImageView imgs;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = (View) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_content, null);
            holder.textviewa = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            holder.textviewb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
            holder.textviewc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);
            holder.textviewd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview4);
            holder.imgs = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textviewa.setText(article.get(position).get("Title"));
        holder.textviewb.setText(article.get(position).get("Description"));
        holder.textviewc.setText(article.get(position).get("PostedTime"));
        holder.textviewd.setText(article.get(position).get("PostedByName"));
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.northmadras.com/upload/Articles/"+article.get(position).get("Image")).into(holder.imgs);
        holder.imgs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context,ArticleContent.class);
                String keyIdentifer  = null;
                i.putExtra("Title", keyIdentifer );
                i.putExtra("Description", keyIdentifer );
                i.putExtra("PostedTime", keyIdentifer );
                i.putExtra("PostedByName", keyIdentifer );
                i.putExtra("image", keyIdentifer );
            }
        });
    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging out the value of `jsonObject.toString()` immediately after the line `JSONObject jsonObject= jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(articleconURL, params);` to see if you're actually getting valid JSON? The error makes it sound like you're attempting to parse an empty JSON object.

Comment: Add the full stack trace and also indicate the line number ..

Comment: This means that you are trying to parse an empty string / response as JSON.  I can't see from your code which `JSONParser` class you are using, but my guess is that it is broken because it doesn't check HTTP response codes.

Comment: This is too much code. Please just post the Json string that you are trying to parse and the code related to the parser.